# css reset margin problem.i cant get rid of margin

Tags: html, css, margin

My problem is that I have a header that is supposed to take up the whole top of the page but for some reason, there is a margin on both sides.I tried * margin :0 padding :0 but doesn't work.
when I add `div.container` margins appears.  i added .container because when i grow the page i want my name and nav to stay in the middle withsome space from the sides.as the picture that i shared but without whitespace/that margins. i hope i could explained
appreciate your help
thanks.

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black
}

html {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 2rem 0.75rem 1rem;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav id="navbar">
        <h1 class="">Hayden Dominic Christiansen</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove ` .container` from your CSS. It will work.

Comment: i need it  i added .container because when i grow the page i want my name and nav to stay in the middle withsome space from the sides.as the picture that i shared but without whitespace/that margins. i hope i could explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the color to the header. See below:

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black
}

html {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace, sans-serif;
}

header { background: yellow; }
 
#navbar {
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 2rem 0.75rem 1rem;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav id="navbar">
        <h1 class="">Hayden Dominic Christiansen</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ooooooh!!!.How i didn't see it for hours. Thanks a lot.It works how i want

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add margin and padding on the body tag.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black
}

header {
    width: 100%;
}

html{
 font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace,sans-serif;
}

#navbar{
   background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding:0.75rem 2rem 0.75rem 1rem;
  
}
#navbar ul{
  list-style-type: none;
   display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
 
<header>
   <div class="container"> 
  <nav id="navbar">
    <h1 class="">Hayden Dominic Christiansen</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div> 
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried but doesnt work :/ i tried html ,header,body. both  everything together or seperatly

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: when i add div container i want all background color to cover the top of the page. when i shink it or grow it

Comment: have you removed .container from css and added header as above? when I run above it is working like you explained.

Comment: oh i got what you mean but i think ,i misinformed you. i added .container because when i grow the page i want my name and nav to stay in the middle withsome space from the sides.as the picture that i shared but without whitespace/that margins. i hope i could explained

Answer (score 0):

Remove the max-width attribute from the the .container selector as it is fixing the width of your navbar to a max of 1100px. Removing it will solve your problem.

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black
}

html {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 2rem 0.75rem 1rem;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}

.container {
  /* max-width: 1100px; Remove this line as it is fixing the navbar to a max of 1100px */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav id="navbar">
        <h1 class="">Hayden Dominic Christiansen</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then try this  `header.container {margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 >!important}`

and lose your job for that xD
first, if you find yourself using important in your own styles, you are doing something wrong.
second, his container is a div, divs do not have any default margins or paddings - nothing to set to 0.

Comment: Please add sources to your claim. While !important should be avoided in most cases, there are reputable sources like CSS-tricks stating that there can be use cases for !important, so this should not be overgeneralized. And please add a code example to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want margin on your container class, try adding

```
.container {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}
```

Comment: Then try this ```` header.container {margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important}````